# biblatex-chicago: first names in text (more than one author)

Tags: biblatex-chicago

Is there a way to include the first names of authors in the \textcite-command in biblatex-chicago? This is what I want to achieve:

[image: James Hathaway and Michelle Foster (2014) wrote a book. On a certain page, they write something particular (123).]

This is what I have achieved so far:

[image: This is a straightforward way: Hathaway and Foster (2014) wrote a book. On a certain page, they write something particular (123). Using textcite and autocite commands works smoothly here. This partly achieves what I want: James Hathaway and Michelle Foster (2014) wrote a book. On a certain page, they write something particular (Hathaway and Foster 2014, 123). Using citeyear and autocite don't go together, it seems.]

Here's the MWEB:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10, twoside=true]{scrbook}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,isbn=false,legalnotes=false,alldates=comp]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
    @book{Hathaway.2014,
        author = {Hathaway, James C. and Foster, Michelle},
        year = {2014},
        title = {The Law of Refugee Status},
        address = {Cambridge},
        publisher = {{Cambridge UP}},
        isbn = {9780511998300},
        doi = {10.1017/CBO9780511998300},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    
% !BIB TS-program = biber
    
This is a straightforward way: \textcite{Hathaway.2014} wrote a book. On a certain page, they write something particular \autocite[123]{Hathaway.2014}. Using textcite and autocite commands works smoothly here.\citereset\\

This partly achieves what I want: James Hathaway and Michelle Foster (\citeyear{Hathaway.2014}) wrote a book. On a certain page, they write something particular \autocite[123]{Hathaway.2014}. Using citeyear and autocite don't go together, it seems.\citereset  
\end{document}
```

How do I get the first names of BOTH authors in the text AND keep the \autocite-command AND keep it short? What's more, I want to vary and use both "James Hathaway and Michelle Foster (2014)" as well as "Hathaway and Foster (2014)" in my text, depending on which version fits stylistically.

Comment: Thank you, @moewe! I tried `\DeclareCiteCommand{\newcitecommand}`, but that opened a whole new can of worms and I ended up with 60 new lines of code (which worked, though)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new version of `\textcite` that locally changes the `labelname` format to output the complete name.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10, twoside=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,isbn=false,legalnotes=false,alldates=comp]{biblatex-chicago}

\newrobustcmd*{\textcitefullname}{%
  \AtNextCite{\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{given-family}}%
  \textcite}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Hathaway.2014,
  author    = {Hathaway, James C. and Foster, Michelle},
  year      = {2014},
  title     = {The Law of Refugee Status},
  address   = {Cambridge},
  publisher = {Cambridge UP},
  isbn      = {9780511998300},
  doi       = {10.1017/CBO9780511998300},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
This is a straightforward way:
\textcite{Hathaway.2014} wrote a book.
On a certain page, they write something particular \autocite[123]{Hathaway.2014}.
Using textcite and autocite commands works smoothly here.
\citereset

Tada:
\textcitefullname{Hathaway.2014} wrote a book.
On a certain page, they write something particular \autocite[123]{Hathaway.2014}.
Using textcite and autocite commands works smoothly here.
\citereset

This partly achieves what I want:
James Hathaway and Michelle Foster \autocite*{Hathaway.2014} wrote a book.
On a certain page, they write something particular \autocite[123]{Hathaway.2014}.
Using citeyear and autocite don't go together, it seems.
\citereset
\end{document}
```

Note that this produces the middle name initial as well, because `biblatex` has no notion of a middle name and all middle names are just treated as being part of the given name.

[image: Tada: James C. Hathaway and Michelle Foster (2014) wrote a book. On a certain page, they write something particular (123). Using textcite and autocite commands works smoothly here.]

---

It is no longer relevant, but don't use `(\citeyear{<key>})` to get the year in `James Hathaway and Michelle Foster (\citeyear{Hathaway.2014})`, use `\autocite*{<key>}` to get a real citation that drops the author name

```
James Hathaway and Michelle Foster \autocite*{Hathaway.2014}
```

Comment: I really don't know why I used `\citeyear{key}` in my example, I only use `\autocite*{key}` in my actual text. Is there a similar caveat concerning `\citetitle{key}`?

Comment: @1stluebbi That depends on which caveats you mean. You can use `\citetitle` if you want to print the title of a `.bib` entry just like you can use `\citeyear` to print the year. Both of these commands disable citation tracking, so will be ignored by "ibid." functions, which could be good, but could also be confusing. In the use case here we don't want to print the year per se, we want to print the citation label (without the name), which happens to be the year (a good rule of thumb is to verify that the same command would work for an author-title instead of an author-year style).